# How do I make the .listen work in node.js for my gcp server. I put in the external IP, and I get this error message: (repost at a more popular time)

Tags: node.js, server, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, ip-address

> events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event= Error: listen
>   EADDRNOTAVAIL 104.154.26.2:3000

**104.154.26.2** is my external ip The .listen looks like this:

```
 serv.listen(3000,"104.154.26.2");
```

I know I should somehow bind the ip address to 0.0.0.0 and that there is some firewall stuff to do, but loads of time researching did nothing.

Comment: Probably some other program / an older instance of your program is using this port already.

Comment: You should configure an NGINX server that can proxy the internet traffic to your node application.

Comment: I dunno specifically about GCP but generally cloud providers have a server like NGINX setup. You just have to tweak the settings so this server knows the `3000` port of your Node Application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the .listen work in node.js for my gcp server. I put in the external IP, and I get this error message:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921689/how-do-i-make-the-listen-work-in-node-js-for-my-gcp-server-i-put-in-the-extern)